# How to prevent overlapping of labels in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, math, three.js

I am trying add labels on sphere, but I am unable to do it only one label is attaching to the sphere and the
rest of labels are overlapping to the corner of the screen. I have also uploaded the image where you can see
the problem. Maybe its css problem,but I dont know exactly. And also I have added the full code. Please help
me with the problem.

[image: image link]

```
div.spritelabel {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
color:#0000FF;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:20px;
text-align: left;
padding:5px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
background:rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 );
}
a:link {color: brown; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none;}
a:visited{color: green; background-color: transparent; text-decoration:    none;}
a:hover{color: red; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline;} 
a:active {color: yellow; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline;}
```

```
window.onload = createsphere();

function createsphere() 
{
var sprite,controls,scene,camera,renderer;
var spritearray = [];
spritearray[0] = {"name": "North", "lat":0, "lon": 10};
spritearray[1] = {"name": "south", "lat":0, "lon": 20};
spritearray[2] = {"name": "East", "lat":0, "lon": 30};
spritearray[3] = {"name": "west", "lat":0, "lon": 40};
function convertlatlonToVec3(lat, lon)
{
    lat = lat * Math.PI / 180.0;
    lon = -lon * Math.PI /180.0;
    return new THREE.Vector3(
        Math.cos(lat)* Math.sin(lon),
        Math.sin(lat)* Math.sin(lon),
        Math.cos(lat));

}

function labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, domElement)
{
    this.screenVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    this.position = convertlatlonToVec3(Ncardinal.lat,Ncardinal.lon).multiplyScalar(radius);
    this.box = document.createElement('div');
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = Ncardinal.name;
    a.href ='http://www.google.de';
    this.box.className = "spritelabel";
    this.box.appendChild(a);

    this.domElement = domElement;
    this.domElement.appendChild(this.box);
}

labelBox.prototype.update = function()
{
this.screenVector.copy(this.position);  
this.screenVector.project(camera);

var posx = Math.round((this.screenVector.x + 1)*   this.domElement.offsetWidth/2);
var posy = Math.round((1 - this.screenVector.y)* this.domElement.offsetHeight/2);

var boundingRect = this.box.getBoundingClientRect();

//update the box overlays position
this.box.style.left = (posx - boundingRect.width) + 'px';
this.box.style.top = posy + 'px';

};



function init() 
        {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.y = 1;
            camera.position.z = 5;

            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);






            var radius = 2.5;
            var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 20, 20, 0, -6.283, 1, 1);
            var texture =  THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ('newimage/crate.jpg');
            texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
            var spherematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, spherematerial);

            scene.add(sphere);
            scene.add(camera);
            scene.autoUpdate = true;

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI/4;
            controls.maxPolarAngle = 3*Math.PI/4;

            for(var i = 0; i< spritearray.length;i++)
            {
                var Ncardinal = spritearray[i];
                sprite =  new labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, document.body);
                var marker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05, 30, 30));
                marker.position.copy(sprite.position);
                scene.add(marker);
            }

            //var Ncardinal = {"name": "North", "lat":0, "lon": 10};
            //sprite =  new labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, document.body);


        }
    function animate() {

    sprite.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
init();
animate();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the debugger output? When I run the code and open googles development mode console I get an error in the `VM112:104 Uncaught TypeError: this.screenVector.project is not a function` which occurs in the labelBox.update method. Looking at the actual object is seems to be a proper Vector3 but there is no project method. This might be because documentation of out of sync with the version of the library you actually have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at how things are set up

```
for(var i = 0; i< spritearray.length;i++)
        {
            var Ncardinal = spritearray[i];
            sprite =  new labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, document.body);
            var marker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05, 30, 30));
            marker.position.copy(sprite.position);
            scene.add(marker);
        }
```

And in your

```
function animate() {

   sprite.update();
   requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
   controls.update();
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Now while initilisation its setting sprite to be the last item in the array. That is the "West" labelBox.

In animate, you just call update on the last sprite set. You can fix this by storing the sprites in an array.

```
var spriteboxes = [];
```

saving them in the spriteloop

```
        for(var i = 0; i< spritearray.length;i++)
        {
            var Ncardinal = spritearray[i];
            sprite =  new labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, document.body);
            var marker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05, 30, 30));
            marker.position.copy(sprite.position);
            scene.add(marker);
            spriteboxes.push(sprite);
        }
```

and change the animate method

```
function animate() {
    spriteboxes.forEach(function(e) { e.update()} );
    sprite.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```